# jQuery events' order of execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/Ly6amgr8/

Clicking the orange bordered area should show `p` tag and run some code.

After the first click, clicking the red ■, should hide the `p` tag, and run some other codes.

the state of `p` is determined with `data-open`, `1/0`.

The problem is that it doesn't matter which `$.on()` I write first, always, the `#switch` code runs first, and changes the `data-open` so the `#parent` code runes and shows the `p` again.

I know about `toggle` but it can not be used here, because the codes and triggers are different.

Comment: Do you want both chunks to execute in a certain order, or do you want to prevent the child container from executing the parents handler?

Comment: @tymeJV First one, do you have any idea about it (certain order)?

Comment: Well I'd imagine `#switch` would always trigger first since it's the child container and the click happens their first - it then bubbles up and executes the parents handler second,

Comment: @tymeJV, if I `stopPropagation()` then clicking the ■, doesn't show p

Comment: Well, the ■ doesn't ever do the opening it seems, only clicking the parent actually runs the toggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is event bubbling `event.stopPropagation()` should fix it . Have updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ly6amgr8/3/

```
$('#container').on('click', '#switch', function(event) {

    // close if is open
    if ($('p').data('open') == 1) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('p').slideUp();
        // Run some other Ajax, etc...
        $('p').data('open',0)
    }
});
```